# Поиск путей к файлам в .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется лог плеера в формате .txt. В логе имеются строки следующего вида:

> [2019-10-06 11:37:41] Opening track for playback: "/Volumes/Storage/test.mp3"

Как можно из всех этих строк средствами Python'а достать пути из кавычек и вывести их в список?

Answer (score 1):

Завел `filename.txt`:

```
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] Opening track for playback: "/Volumes/Storage/test.mp3"
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] ...
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] Opening track for playback: "/Volumes/Storage/test1.mp3"
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] ...
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] Opening track for playback: "/Volumes/Storage/test2.mp3"
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] ...
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] ...
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] Opening track for playback: "/Volumes/Storage/test3.mp3"
[2019-10-06 11:37:41] ...
```

Реализация через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

items = []

with open("filename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search('"(.+?)"', line)
        if m:
            items.append(m.group(1))

print(items)
# ['/Volumes/Storage/test.mp3', '/Volumes/Storage/test1.mp3', '/Volumes/Storage/test2.mp3', '/Volumes/Storage/test3.mp3']
```

---

Регулярное выражение `"(.+?)"` захватывает все символы внутри кавычек. При желании, выражение можно сделать специфичным, например только для mp3:

```
"(.+?\.mp3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```py
my_list = list()

with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list.append(line.split('"')[1])

print(my_list)
```

`filename` - имя вашего файла. Абсолютное либо относительное.